# how to load data from tfrecord files only once

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am playing with `tf.data.Dataset` and tfrecord files to figure out the bottle neck in my tensorflow code. In the toy script below, in the second epoch, the data are erased and cannot be read from disk.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()

xs = [[1,2,3], [2,4,45,5],[5,5,56,2]]
names = ['a','b','c']
os.mkdir('foo')
for name, x in zip(names, xs):
    features = tf.train.Features(feature={
        'x': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=x))})
    ex = tf.train.Example(features=features)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(f'foo/{name}')
    writer.write(ex.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()

def _parse_function(example_proto):
    features={'x':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
            }
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    return parsed_features

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['foo/'+ f for f in os.listdir('foo')])
dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=3)
dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset.cache()
dataset.repeat(3)
for i in range(3):
    if i == 1:
        for f in os.listdir('foo'):
            os.remove('foo/'+f)
    for d in dataset:
        print(d)
```

In the second epoch I got this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:
foo/c; No such file or directory [Op:IteratorGetNextSync].
```

This means `tf.data.TFRecordDataset()` reads data from disk each epoch even with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset.cache()`.

I imagined the whole dataset would be cached in memory, and file io might not happen after the first epoch. This is not the case apparently. What does the `cache()` method do? Also, is there any way to load the whole tfrecord files only once in the beginning of training?

Comment: Check your path to the file or directory

Comment: @bigbounty The file does not exist because I erased it on purpose from disk. I thought the data are kept on memory. However, dataset actually tried to read the data from disk repeatedly, and I want to change the behavior a bit.